# How can I group by and sum without using all selected columns using SQL Server/MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2010

SQL newbie here...

Here's a sample of my table named TEST in MS Access:

```
EFF_DATE   BATCH   ENTITY ACCOUNT  TRANS_AMT
12/1/2017  TEST A  110    165105   (10.00)
12/1/2017  TEST A  120    278910    10.00 
12/1/2017  TEST A  110    165105   (10.00)
12/1/2017  TEST A  120    165135    10.00 
12/2/2017  TEST B  120    165135    15.00 
12/2/2017  TEST B  110    278910   (10.00)
```

In my query, I'm trying to sum by EFF_DATE and BATCH only and exclude TRANS_AMT sums equaling 0.

So my query results should be the following:

```
EFF_DATE   BATCH   ENTITY  ACCOUNT  TRANS_AMT
12/2/2017  TEST B  120     165135   15.00 
12/2/2017  TEST B  110     278910  (10.00)
```

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
EFF_DATE, 
BATCH, 
ENTITY, 
ACCOUNT, 
Sum(TRANS_AMT) 
FROM TEST
WHERE ACCOUNT in ("165105","278910","165135")
AND ENTITY in ("120","110")
GROUP BY TEST.EFF_DATE, TEST.BATCH
HAVING (((Sum(TRANS_AMT))<>0));
```

I get the following error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ENTITY' as part of an aggregate function."

When I googled the error I couldn't find any information other than stating that the other columns should be added to the GROUP BY clause but if I add them, then the transactions that should sum to zero by date and batch continue to show up. Any ideas on what I can do to get the desired result?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use something in a grouped select statement, it needs to be in the group by.

However, you can do this nesting.

You can all the effective date/batch combinations and are non-zero.

Then only select outer records pertaining to them.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST A
WHERE (A.EFF_DATE, A.BATCH) IN
(
    SELECT B.EFF_DATE, B.BATCH
    FROM TEST B
    GROUP BY B.EFF_DATE, B.BATCH
    HAVING Sum(B.TRANS_AMT)<>0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amend you GROUP BY and include ENTITY, and ACCOUNT

```
GROUP BY TEST.EFF_DATE, TEST.BATCH, ENTITY, ACCOUNT
```